# How to manage JPA entity in Spring boot micro services?

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I have two micro services with the shared database. like user management service and organization management service. both services have its own entities.

now the problem is I have to manage one to many relationship between organization and user, I have few solutions with doubt.

**solutions :**

> 1. I can duplicate entities in both services (but if there is any change in entity like add or remove attribute, I have to take care in
>      all services).
> 2. I can create a shared jar for entities (but in case of change in entities, I have to restart both services)
> 3. I can fire pure `SQL` query.

any other suggestion or help will save my day.

please suggest me a better solution!!

Comment: I added the [architecture] tag since that seems what your question is about. If it is about a more technical side of the problem the question might need an update.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to try to follow the (good) advice that a microservice should maintain its own data and be as independent as possible from other services. Taking this as the premise Domain Driven Design offers helpful advice.

Your microservices manage one (or a group of) Aggregate each. An Aggregate is a cluster of instances that

- stay consistent at all times (except for within a method call to the Aggregate Root)
- get stored and loaded atomically from a persistence store.

Each Aggregate has exactly one Aggregate Root. It's component only get accessed through methods of the Aggregate Root. This allows the Aggregate Root to ensure consistency.

Combination of Aggregates are only eventually consistent, i.e. they might be inconsistent at a given point of time but eventually will become consistent. This allows keeping the Aggregates simple since they don't need to bother themselves about the state of other Aggregates. In order to allow that Aggregates refer to each other only by id.

So here is how you apply that to your situation.

If you design the `Person` entity for your microservices you will probably discover that they don't have the same attributes. For example, the User Management Service might need a **hashed** password for a `Person`. The Organization Management Service might have other attributes, or maybe even none at all except an id.

Therefore you should have separate classes for those. Now there are different approaches to combine these two Aggregates depending on how they are designed. Let's start with the easiest:

If the `Person` is completely owned by one service everything else just needs the id. In a web application you could (and possibly should) just include a link to the person resource and load any detail information you want to display using the owning service of the `Person`. You can also do that in your backend but that is a decision for another day.

If both services have common attributes (e.g. you might want to include basic information like the `name` in the Organization Management Service so you can display something human readable even when the other service is not available.
In this case, you can use events to notify services of changes they need to apply to their version of the entity.

Note that you want to decouple any event handling from the rest of your services so that.

a) a problem in with the event infrastructure doesn't cause problems with the service trying to publish events.

b) you have a process in place to sync information when the event infrastructure was unavailable for some time.

One important property to maintain is that every attribute is only changed by one service. If you don't maintain that it gets really difficult to find out which is the correct variant if the values of an attribute diverge.